# Gdiplus in C++ managed or unmanaged?

Tags: c++, gdi+, unmanaged, managed-c++

is this file  with namespace Gdiplus in c++ managed or unmanaged code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unmanaged.  The managed wrapper is the System::Drawing namespace.